# Unable to run NET SHARE as an administrator

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, administrator

In Windows 10, I am trying to use NET SHARE to share a root drive 'X' and set permissions. Drive 'X' is a drive mapped by BoxCryptor Classic (FAT32 type). 
In a bat file 'myscript.bat', I am using:

```
NET SHARE MyShare /DELETE /Y
NET SHARE MyShare=X: /GRANT:MyUser,Full /UNLIMITED /CACHE:None
```

When running the file elevated as an administrator, this works fine. It says the share is deleted, then it says the share is shared.

But I want to run it at startup so I use another bat file, using runas with an administrator account. Then I get 'System Error 5 Access Is Denied':

```
RUNAS /SAVECRED /user:MYDOMAIN\MyUser "path/to/myscript.bat"
```

MyUser is an administrator and I made sure the BoxCryptor share is mounted. 
What could be the problem here?

Cheers,
Kjeld

Comment: Being an administrator and being Administrator aren't really the same thing. Also have you looked into other possibilities such as Group Policies or Scheduled Tasks?

Comment: @Compo Can you elaborate a little more on how administrator is different in the two situations described? The user MyUser is in a group of administrators. Do you mean to schedule a task that runs after startup? Would this solve the problem?

Comment: You probably need to run that as an elevated administrator.  So many people were logging into their windows boxes as admins, Microsoft had to restrict them for their own good.  Use TaskScheduler, it will ensure your code runs at a point after the boot that allows whatever privileges you specify and you won't need the extra script.

Comment: Using task scheduler did the trick, albeit the drive properties say it is not shared. I can however verify that it works, by trying to access the share from the network (it seems to act according to permissions set). Thanks. I used a trigger that starts one minute after boot, so it gives Boxcryptor Classic a little time to mount the shares first. It would however be even better if the application would trigger the task. Cannot seem to find an event to do that though..